# What kind of gun did Leon use to shoot Holden in Blade Runner?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

Early in the film, Dave Holden, a Blade Runner, administers the Voight-Kampff test to the replicant Leon. Leon shoots Holden before the test is finished. I have questions:

1. How did Leon get a gun into the room with him?
2. It's absolutely clear that Leon pulls the trigger under the table, but things on top of the table get blown up by the bullet Leon shoots. What?
3. The shot from Leon's gun is so powerful, it literally blows Holden through the wall behind him. How is that possible?

Number one is just a hand-wave. Number two seems like a pretty big editing error. Number three I just don't understand.

Comment: http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Blade_Runner

Comment: In the original script it was a laser pistol. "*But big Leon is faster.  His
        laser burns a hole the size of a nickel through
        Holden's stomach.  Unlike a bullet, a laser causes
        no impact.  It goes through Holden's shoulder and
        comes out his back, clean as a whistle.  Like a
        rag doll he falls back into the seat.  Big slow Leon
        is already walking away, but he stops, turns, and
        with a little smile of satisfaction fires through
        the back of the seat.*" - https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/blade-runner_shooting.html

Comment: All of these questions seem broadly answerable within the same quote space

Comment: Leon's gun being powerful and blowing a hole through the wall is standard scifi trope. I'm not sure what the question even is, "is scifi realistic?". Well, no, it's not realistic -- it's played for effect/emotion. Next question? (also notice: lightsabers in Star Wars make absolutely no sense; do we worry about that?)

Answer (score 5):

- *How did Leon get a gun into the room with him?*

It is pretty much assumed that he smuggled it in. There is no backstory to the security setup to refer to, and there is no script for that. Additionally the pistol is small, the kind of thing a big guy, as Leon is, could secrete upon his person without being too obvious. Though he does walk kinda funny (enlarged gait) when he arrives at Holdens office...

- *It's absolutely clear that Leon pulls the trigger under the table, but things on top of the table get blown up by the bullet Leon shoots. What?*

Two things to note:

- The height of the table they are sat at.

From the seated position that Leon is in, the effect is from him shooting not horizontally but slightly upwards, so he shoots through the table and *up* into Holdens chest.

[image]

- note that both are hunched over slightly, that is because both have drawn their weapons, under the table, but Leon is first to fire his.
- They added a 'laser' effect that shows it shot up through the table, past the monitor in the middle of the table towards Holden, and clearly above the table top. Therefore its path is through the items that you see jumping about.

[image]

pretty horrible, but its there

[image]

- *The shot from Leon's gun is so powerful, it literally blows Holden through the wall behind him. How is that possible?*

Its not made clear what the wall is made up of, but you can see in the establishing shot that these are nothing but partitions, not solid walls, so why shouldn't they be able to be punched through? If it was drywall for example, thats pretty easy to knock through.

[image]

But also, why shouldn't the gun be powerful?
This is Hollywood after all, and this is the 'future' as well.
Note how they modified the gun to fire two barrels at once for greater effect. They wanted this small pistol to have a big impact and a big effect (with added sound effects too). None of this is supposed to be realistic or set in todays world.

The book had everyone shooting laserpistols, laser needles or some such, which would generally have less of an effect on film. Audiences still expect to have bangs and lots of noise, even in the 'future'.

- *Number one is just a hand-wave. Number two seems like a pretty big editing error. Number three I just don't understand.*

I agree the first is a handwave, but the next two are what vfx, sfx, and sound guys, etc, do for a living. They get told to enhance stuff, make it bigger, have more effect. So thats what you see - Ridley wanting a big bang from a small pistol.

BR storyboard frame, showing they wanted the gun to shoot from under the table and through items on the table, into Holden.

[image]

(Artist: Mentor Huebner)

Comment: Just to add, Scott originally had a black hole gun in mind, but it was scrapped as it didn't look so impressive, but they left the visual effect in the shot, which is likely to be  the weird laser bolt circled in the answer. https://media.bladezone.com/contents/film/technology/blackhole.php

Comment: Interesting about the bolt! Is this in the Director's Cut? To be clear, I've watched this movie dozens of time (my all-time scifi favorite) and I never even noticed the laser bolt!

Comment: @AndresF. - hard to say, best bet for me would be to fire up my vhs player and pull out the tape. But I can't remember where i stored the player... Anyway, most available sources seem to have it: https://youtu.be/Umc9ezAyJv0?si=b618uRJnYZEjC_Kd&t=168

Comment: One thing for sure, the weird laser is very noticeable in the Final Cut version I have.

Comment: @Clockwork with it not being too noticeable in the original, I wonder f they tweaked it to make more of it. It's only a few frames anyway, and most people easily miss it.

Comment: @Clockwork tangential, but bear with me: the Final Cut makes many odd "image" decisions, which reminds me of a post I saw in Reddit re: Batman TAS DVD vs 4K version: the DVD is arguably superior *because* the image is less sharp! So in movie-making terms, "sharper" or "higher res" is not better; those are tech specs, but do not a good movie make. Sometimes blurrier/harder to see is better because it serves the "art" better. In the case of Blade Runner, I find the greenish Matrix-like tint of the Final Cut *worse* than the earthier/bluish tint of the DC. And this bolt thing would be another one

Comment: @AndresF. You mean like how people like to play SNES games on CRT? I found the Final cut to be okay, although I definitely see what you mean with some other stuffs I watched. The last thing I read about the subject was how they purposely used a handheld camera to film the entire _28 Days Later_ movie.

Answer (score -2):

I think Leon is being interviewed at Tyrell, maybe the security was not very good. Same sort of blaster that Deckard used, much more powerful than a normal pistol and perhaps rocket propelled so that its thrust as it passes under the table is disruptive and at close range can in fact send someone though a wall. Maybe such guns are necessary for killing replicants and therefore would be the sort of weapon a replicant would use in their battles off-world with other replicants and would naturally be the weapons they brought with them to Earth.